# Create a raw transaction and broadcast it to blockchain using bitcoin core

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, createrawtransaction, sendrawtransaction

I have a address- `n3xYQtxvVwpBPSbgGsGRdMWz1YTUjakiMV`, amount  that i want to send-`1 BTC` and i have a `private key`. How can i create a raw transaction using it and broadcast it to blockchain using bitcoin core.

I have tried this command:

```
bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"dbdc2e2c7f143af70c5e7e8725f55d226b3c058d7bf34a303‌​091b3c6a514848c","vo‌​ut":1}]' '{"n3xYQtxvVwpBPSbgGsGRdMWz1YTUjakiMV":1}'
```

and this: `bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction XXX`

Comment: I have tried this command :bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"dbdc2e2c7f143af70c5e7e8725f55d226b3c058d7bf34a303091b3c6a514848c","vout":1}]' '{"n3xYQtxvVwpBPSbgGsGRdMWz1YTUjakiMV":1}'

and this:

bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction XXX

Comment: But i want to perform transaction using specific private key

Comment: I don't  want to import private key in wallet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT: based on OPs request, I put examples in here:**

there are a lot of examples for different tx types on bitcoin.org, in the [developer examples](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-spending). Basically you will need three steps. Assuming you are on OpenBSD/MacOS/Linux, you can go this way:

**1.) createrawtransaction** - this is what you have already, and it looks ok. I don't know if the previous tx ID or v_out is correct, assuming you know the details, your string is ok (otherwise check with "bitcoin-cli -regtest listunspent", and adopt TX_ID and V_OUT accordingly). I also assume, that the address is one which is in your wallet. Otherwise you might just create an address, and proceed afterwards like this:

```
UTXO_TXID=dbdc2e2c7f143af70c5e7e8725f55d226b3c058d7bf34a303‌
UTXO_VOUT=1
NEW_ADDRESS=n3xYQtxvVwpBPSbgGsGRdMWz1YTUjakiMV
bitcoin-cli -regtest createrawtransaction '''
    [
      {
        "txid": "'$UTXO_TXID'",
        "vout": '$UTXO_VOUT'
      }
    ]
    ''' '''
    {
      "'$NEW_ADDRESS'": 1
    }'''
```

you provide this returned hex string to another variable:

```
RAW_TX=01000...
```

**2.) signrawtransaction** - the previous command returns a hex string, that you will use to sign the transaction - again, see the docs. First I verify my created tx, and then sign:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest decoderawtransaction $RAW_TX
bitcoin-cli -regtest signrawtransaction $RAW_TX
```

again you assign the result to a variable:

```
SIGNED_RAW_TX=01000...
```

**3.) sendrawtransaction** - again you take the hexstring of the previous command as parameter, and/or see the docs.

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest sendrawtransaction $SIGNED_RAW_TX
```

and maybe a verification as step 4:

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 1
```

this generates a block, and you can see on the $NEW_ADDRESS, if funds have been transferred.

I just entered the two keywords here in the search function, and also found a lot of answers.

Comment: Can you provide me some ways to create txid in rawtransaction. It would be better if you can post it to your answer

Comment: is there any single command available in bitcoin core that is equivalent to `createrawtransaction,signrawtransaction,sendrawtransaction`

Comment: I am not aware of such a command...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`signrawtransaction`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#signrawtransaction), this method accept an array of private keys as an argument.

Parameter #3—private keys for signing:

> An array holding private keys. *If any keys are provided, only they
>   will be used to sign the transaction (even if the wallet has other
>   matching keys).* If this array is empty or not used, and wallet support
>   is enabled, keys from the wallet will be used

Comment: Can you provide me some ways to create txid in rawtransaction

Comment: @AjitSoman there is a lot of examples, in [the documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpcs)