# Create unsigned tx (PSBT) in a watch-only wallet using bitcoin core, sign it in electrum and broadcast using bitcoin core

Tags: watch-only, bip174-psbt

What are the steps that we can follow to create an unsigned tx for watch-only cold storage address using bitcoin core? How can we sign the transaction and broadcast it later?

Answer (score 2):

[image: create wallet]

[image: cold-storage-example]

Run the below commands in electrum console:

```
>> getaddresshistory('tb1qu2l4n8st9w3hhsxstd8muaxgnu63fql9rkylmd')
[
    {
        "height": 1807710,
        "tx_hash": "727707cced87f9bc2a1ca3ed28df39588e9881fd50c272e78bc76a5bb1ffde9c"
    }
]
>> deserialize(gettransaction('727707cced87f9bc2a1ca3ed28df39588e9881fd50c272e78bc76a5bb1ffde9c'))
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "coinbase": false,
            "nsequence": 4294967295,
            "prevout_hash": "99ebe2d047c545a50cf86f0ff5f4c0648437cb8724137f1a33c2f06eb06ef35a",
            "prevout_n": 1,
            "scriptSig": "",
            "witness": "0247304402206379d344d75fbee07f54213378f95e44dc757872d59a35efbc14ec7e1ca7dfd102207a47f9c1be39cafa8f9ac8a879e2b968e2359bead23a1f6598478ed7d141c73d012103ee169045615c663c0204472f86e3c2b2ae43e574146d30607c42fe6d670ac7be"
        }
    ],
    "locktime": 0,
    "outputs": [
        {
            "address": "tb1qu2l4n8st9w3hhsxstd8muaxgnu63fql9rkylmd",
            "scriptpubkey": "0014e2bf599e0b2ba37bc0d05b4fbe74c89f351483e5",
            "value_sats": 3000000
        },
        {
            "address": "tb1q7sx47sra5w7kw8we5xeusl4089ryverhjcft6q",
            "scriptpubkey": "0014f40d5f407da3bd671dd9a1b3c87eaf3946466477",
            "value_sats": 61797954
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

You get the scriptPubKey in above output which can be used in `importmulti` command in bitcoin core:

```
"address": "tb1qu2l4n8st9w3hhsxstd8muaxgnu63fql9rkylmd",
"scriptpubkey": "0014e2bf599e0b2ba37bc0d05b4fbe74c89f351483e5"
```

Get the public key of the address from details:

[image: address-details-electrum]

If you are using bitcoin core wallet instead of electrum in this example, you can run the `getaddressinfo` command in console to get `scriptPubKey` and `pubkey` of the address.

Run the below command in bitcoin core console to import the address with the details copied from electrum:

```
importmulti '[{"scriptPubKey" : "0014e2bf599e0b2ba37bc0d05b4fbe74c89f351483e5","pubkeys" : ["0304c5184085eea27a072628de03fbb953f5fdd99fb526f097fdd4c6968d165f1a"],"timestamp" : "now","label" : "watch-address-test", "watchonly": true}
```

**You can ignore the steps mentioned above for scriptPubKey and only use the "Public Key" of an address by using [descriptor](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md):**

We need checksum in `importmulti` which is returned in `descriptorinfo` for the public key mentioned

[image: descriptorinfo]

Next, we can run `importmulti` command (I have used public key for a different address in this command):

```
importmulti '[{"desc" : "wpkh(026641b79d7ffa40ddf994f0277c2649f3ddcbd871194ba6ef87687daea22ca503)#zl4yt8hu","timestamp" : "now","label" : "watch-address-test", "watchonly": true}]'
```

[image: receiving-address]

```
rescanblockchain 1800000 1835099
```

I can see available inputs in GUI:

[image: inputs]

We still get an error if trying to create an unsigned tx which involves sending some amount to change address because we aren't trying to spend the whole balance.

[image: change-error]

Add a change address for creating unsigned tx:

[image: add-change-address]

Option to copy PSBT:

[image: PSBT]

Load transaction using the copied text in electrum:

[image: load-tx]

[image: sign-tx]

Copy the hex of signed tx and run the below command in bitcoin core:

```
sendrawtransaction 020000000001019cdeffb15b6ac78be772c250fd81988e5839df28eda31c2abcf987edcc0777720000000000fdffffff02b3410f0000000000160014112c8ecb9e0876a645e7b8e89eed83bd61096e2c80841e00000000001600145f24e8fbfe65840c27dad3b053855de4cee843820247304402200d7cc29a8588c180e6a460e0eb88ea830db76dbb040a875d45fe8c64c9509a80022060879365af1c6d19e7c47bdbfa402a053ed42809c52db6816cd249dff46529b001210304c5184085eea27a072628de03fbb953f5fdd99fb526f097fdd4c6968d165f1a5f001c00
```

**It returns the transaction id:** `4890c14e7635a3e72320046645686052339e443eba56e5a62849a48b3f67f419`

You can check the details in a block explorer: **https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/4890c14e7635a3e72320046645686052339e443eba56e5a62849a48b3f67f419**

*Related questions:*

[How to create unsigned tx in a watch-only wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99046/how-to-create-unsigned-tx-in-a-watch-only-wallet)

[How to move/sweep your Bitcoin Core bitcoins safely and air-gapped to your new fancy cold storage?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98715/how-to-move-sweep-your-bitcoin-core-bitcoins-safely-and-air-gapped-to-your-new-f)

*Related issues:*
https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui/issues/94