# is wallet vulnerable when unlocked for transactions?

Tags: transactions, security, exchanges, network, privacy

is wallet vulnerable when unlocked for transactions?.I recovered a wallet some time ago and all is good.passphrase key all looks good.But a question came to my mind about the moment we make a transaction.I guess we must be connected to the net blockchain or however  you call it.Also we unlock the wallet for the transactions right or wrong? if yes,does that not make the wallet vulnereble for hacking even for a few minuites?help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create, sign and broadcast transaction on different machines. When private keys are offline it's called cold storage.

Example: [Create unsigned tx (PSBT) in a watch-only wallet using bitcoin core, sign it in electrum and broadcast using bitcoin core](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99111/create-unsigned-tx-psbt-in-a-watch-only-wallet-using-bitcoin-core-sign-it-in)

Comment: you are kidding me