# Create a .psbt using the BitcoinCore client

Tags: bitcoin-core, coldstorage, bip174-psbt

I am trying to create a .psbt using BitcoinCore on mainnet. The use-case is that I want to be able to export the unsigned transaction, import it into my cold-storage wallet (using BitcoinCore) and sign it, to then broadcast it. I have successfully done this using Electrum as a hot wallet to generate the transaction, but would like to move away from any third party software.

Basically I am trying to follow the steps from [this post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99111/create-unsigned-tx-psbt-in-a-watch-only-wallet-using-bitcoin-core-sign-it-in), but it does not work. The problem is that BitcoinCore will recognize the balance as watch only (as it should) but when trying to create a transaction I can not find the coin inputs listed anywhere (under the Coin Control feature).

The base transaction is [b69314fff08ae8b58c41d653ea212d9e1f2ecf683f0ea96ee5f9c52f22b0a189](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/b69314fff08ae8b58c41d653ea212d9e1f2ecf683f0ea96ee5f9c52f22b0a189/) and my address is [bc1q4xuxxf6mmcyk9q3k3lufhr7rlsn9hzhrvkdgqz](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/bc1q4xuxxf6mmcyk9q3k3lufhr7rlsn9hzhrvkdgqz/). For Electrum, all I had to do to generate a .psbt was importing the address. I have tried importing the address into BitcoinCore using

```
importaddress bc1q4xuxxf6mmcyk9q3k3lufhr7rlsn9hzhrvkdgqz
```

and also importing the public key using the `importpubkey` command, then re-scanning the wallet. Nothing worked.

I also tried the following command (and multiple variations of it) which some people claimed fixed the issue for them:

```
importmulti '[{"desc": "wpkh([a9b86327]0391f12147a67c291785baf634187f7ad24d4e491b07f53543a33f7705736efeb6)#jpxe908h","timestamp": "now","watchonly": true}]'
```

using inputs provided by `getaddressinfo`. Again no coin inputs were selectable after re-scanning the wallet.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I am a bit confused why BitcoinCore will not allow me to create a .psbt even though Electrum did instantly (and I was subsequently able to import and sign it using BitcoinCore).

Also, would someone be able to explain in simple terms what the `desc` field is doing? [From what I gather](https://bitcoindevkit.org/descriptors/), it holds a descriptor that tells the wallet how to generate addresses, but I could use a short example to understand it better.

Comment: Did you create the wallet with private keys disabled?

Comment: No, addresses generated within the wallet have private keys (using dumpprivkey). I left the standard settings unchanged when I created it.

Comment: You will need to use a wallet with private keys disabled (choose that option when creating the wallet) in order for the `Create unsigned` button to appear.

Comment: Thank you, turns out this solves it. Intuitively I assumed a full-wallet would have a superset of the functionality of a watch-only one and was therefore expecting the problem to be more complex. If you like to post it as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Create Unsigned" button is only available to wallets with private keys disabled (i.e. watch only wallets). So you will need to create a new wallet and choose the "Disable private keys" option.