Load PSBT error: Unable to decode PSBT
I test PSBT in my wallet today, create a transaction in Bitcoin Core, click "send" and "create unsigned", then "Load PSBT from ..." from menu, error shows:
Unable to decode PSBT 
Unsigned tx does not have empty scriptSigs and scriptWitnesses.: unspecified iostream_category error

decodepsbt and analyzepsbt show the same error too:
TX decode failed Unsigned tx does not have empty scriptSigs and scriptWitnesses.: unspecified iostream_category error (code -22)

I have no ideal what happened. But same procedure works fine in another wallet of testnet. Both wallets are not watch-only. Besides, I'm using prune mode for block chain. This address I made tx was obtained by importprivkey, and then covert to Descriptor Wallets by migratewallet.
I found the source code, any clarification is welcome:
                case PSBT_GLOBAL_UNSIGNED_TX:
                {
                    if (!key_lookup.emplace(key).second) {
                        throw std::ios_base::failure("Duplicate Key, unsigned tx already provided");
                    } else if (key.size() != 1) {
                        throw std::ios_base::failure("Global unsigned tx key is more than one byte type");
                    }
                    CMutableTransaction mtx;
                    // Set the stream to serialize with non-witness since this should always be non-witness
                    UnserializeFromVector(s, TX_NO_WITNESS(mtx));
                    tx = std::move(mtx);
                    // Make sure that all scriptSigs and scriptWitnesses are empty
                    for (const CTxIn& txin : tx->vin) {
                        if (!txin.scriptSig.empty() || !txin.scriptWitness.IsNull()) {
                            **throw std::ios_base::failure("Unsigned tx does not have empty scriptSigs and scriptWitnesses.");**
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }


The "Create Unsigned" button is only available to wallets with private keys disabled (i.e. watch only wallets)(https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/112432/147825), But the button is active to click in bitcoin core 27.0 with my non-watchonly wallet.

I'm not able to replicate this error. Regarding the button being there, it added for non-watchonly wallets sometime in the past few years, so that's expected.

@AvaChow，I'm using prune mode for block chain.

@AvaChow, what does error message "Unsigned tx does not have empty scriptSigs and scriptWitnesses." mean? does it mean that unsigned tx information carries signed info?

@AvaChow, I don't know does it matter. This address was obtained by importprivkey, and then covert to Descriptor Wallets by migratewallet.
